# Renderizar um html no node com js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Eu posso uma rota no node onde chama uma página html, porém a página html possui um arquivo .js e quando ela é chamada da erro de não achar o arquivo JS.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Estrutura:

pasta principal : projeto

sub pastas: config, js, views

dentro de config:config.js
dentro de js: request.js
dentro de views: index.html

config.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var port = 3000;
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extend : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.listen(port);


app.set('views', './views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));

module.exports.express = function(){
    return app;
}
```

app.js(está localizado na pasta principal):

```
var app = require('./config/config.js').express();
app.get('/',function(req,res){

  res.render('index.html');
});
```

Comment: Poste seu código node, html e a estrutura das pastas

Comment: ve se ajuda, eu editei

Comment: Esse `arquivo.js` é um ficheiro para correr no servidor ou pra ser chamado do HTML e corrido no browser?

Answer (score 1):

Coloque `config.js` na pasta raiz, assim fica mais fácil manter o projeto, e os arquivos da aplicação na pasta `app`(pode escolher qualquer nome), `index.html` pode ficar isolado, pois também fica mais fácil manter, outros templates podem ser alocados na pasta `views`

> config.js
>
> app
>
> > index.html
> >
> > js > request.js
> >
> > views > outrasTelas.html

E ache o index com o `express`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar código javascript dentro do nodejs com express é simples:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'nome_da_pasta_com_seus_arquivos_js')))
```

Depois é só referenciar no seu arquivo html o arquivo js que vc quiser e reiniar o servidor.